# How to show HTML tags via JavasScript string

Tags: javascript, html, astrojs

I have an Astro component where I want to write text with  tags. The problem is that the tags like "**characteristic1**" are not converted into HTML code, they stay as a string.

This component has a field for the characteristics of a product and it may have different size depending on the product:

```
<Plan
  title="title here" 
  subtitle="subtitle here" 
  characteristics={["characteristic1", 
                    "characteristic2",
                    ...
                   ]}
/>
```

This is represented by the following code in other file:

```
---
const { title, subtitle, characteristics } = Astro.props;
---

<p class="title">{title}</p>
<p class="subtitle">{subtitle}</p>

{characteristics?.map((item) => (
  <p class="text">{item}</p>
))}
```

It's supposed that when you write HTML code in a string in JS it's treated as HTML code but I don't know why it's treated as a string.

How can I convert the tags into HTML code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you try use of **set:html**?? So instead of ```<p class="text">{item}</p>```, do it like this ```<p class="text" set:html={item}></p>```

Comment: Now works, thank you very much! I searched a lot of information and I didn't see this property

Comment: `set:html` should not be needed, and indeed should be avoided if possible, because if your string contains HTML, it will be inserted as is, which can be a security risk if the string comes from an untrusted source like user input.

the code in the question works for me in the newes astro version? e.g. i could not reproduce it in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vtv1pt?file=src%2Fpages%2Findex.astro)

Answer (score 0):

As [Keyboard Corporation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21370707/keyboard-corporation) says (I think that I can't mark his comment as the answer) it is solved by using `<p class="text" set:html={item}></p>`. Thanks for your answer!